# How do declare date variables in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, date, variables, plsql, declare

I am new to PL/SQL and don't understand how to declare date variables. How would I write this T-SQL script in PL/SQL?

```
declare @date1 as date
declare @date2 as date

set @date1 = '2022-06-01'
set @date2 = '2022-06-30'

select * 
from example_table
where example_date between @date1 and @date2
```

Answer (score 1):

Declaring variables is easy.

Problem comes when you want to do something with the `select` statement as PL/SQL requires you to select `INTO` *something* (a local variable, set of local variables, ref cursor, collection, ...). You didn't say what you'd want to do afterwards, so the following example

- selects number of rows that satisfy condition
- loops through the table and does nothing (`null;`) for each loop iteration.

You'd do something else, I presume.

```
declare
  date1 date := date '2022-06-01';
  date2 date := date '2022-06-30';
  l_cnt number;
begin
  select count(*)
    into l_cnt
    from example_table
    where example_date between date1 and date2;

  for cur_r in (select *
                from example_table
                where example_date between date1 and date2 
               )
  loop
    null;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: To add to this answer, be careful of columns where there are also times (other than midnight/00:00:00 (which is the default time allocated if you don't specify a specific time portion)) - the between query will find rows where the example_date column is between `2022-06-01 00:00:00` and `2022-06-30 00:00:00`. If your column contains dates such as `2022-06-30 18:23:46` that you also want to be returned, you're going to have to change your query to `where example_date >= date1 and example_date < date2 + 1` instead.